# Is the similarity between Bane and Venom a coincidence?

Tags: marvel, dc, comics, venom, bane

It always appeared to me that the DC Comics character Bane and Marvel's Venom show many similarities:

- both are arch-nemeses for main costumed heroes in their respective comic books,
- both gain their power from external source called Venom (I know that technically the symbiote's name is not Venom, but it's often referred to with it),
- both were physically adept even before gaining superhuman strength,
- Bane's masked appearance looks a bit similar to Venom:

  [image: Bane] [image: Venom]

Has there been any creator commentary, or official word from Marvel or DC, on this subject? I'm looking for discussion in interviews or trade publications, press releases, or (if it got that far) legal filings - anything discussing the (notable, if only to me) similarities.

Alternately, if there's evidence that the similarities in appearance both go back to some common influence (like Green Arrow and Hawkeye could both be inspired by Robin Hood), I'd like to know about that.

Comment: I have nothing to back this up hence it's just a comment, but it seems like coincidence. I mean, if you reduce most antagonist comic book characters down to a bullet point list of half a dozen points or fewer, you're often going to get a _lot_ of crossover. If you focus on their differences rather than their similarities, they don't seem to be all that similar at all.

Comment: *"both are arch-nemeses for main costumed heroes"*  Isn't this true for all supervillains in all comic books?

Comment: @Steve-O Definitely, but I wouldn't be looking for similarities if any of them would be just one-issue villian-of-the-month. On the contrary, both appear to be very tied to their masked heroes' stories and are very significant characters, so the perceived similarity started to get me wondering. It may still be nothing, of course.

Comment: @delinear I don't know, to me it's about the same level of similarity as Sentry vs Superman and Hawkeye vs Green Arrow, and in both cases the insipiration is considered obvious. It's always a bit subjective of course, that's why I'm asking about any official sources confirming/denying it.

Comment: Some dates, for reference: Marvel's Venom appeared with that name in *Amazing Spider-Man* #300, cover-dated May 1988. DC's Venom (the drug) appeared in the March 1991 issue of *Legends of the Dark Knight*. Bane appeared about 2 years later, in 1993.

Comment: @Steve-O - Personally, I would think of *arch*-nemeses as being the *first* opponents you think of when you think of a hero - their most significant/challenging foes. The Fantastic Four and Dr. Doom. Superman and Lex Luthor. Batman and the Joker. Spider-Man and the Green Goblin. As Red indicates, with these characters, it's the similarities between the hero and villain, and the fact that the villain's origin in some way is directly tied to the hero's history. That said, as noted above, I wouldn't really consider either an arch-nemesis, personally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite lukewarm reaction to my question, I kept looking from time to time for any kind of answer and found [this](http://sequart.org/magazine/9017/the-bane-venom-connection/) piece of editorial.

The author brings another similarity that I didn't previously notice: both Venom the drug and Venom the Symbiote were previously used and rejected by respective series' heroes, Batman and Spider-Man. But the relevant part is:

> I have, however, read a ton of comics and a decent amount of
>   interviews about the background of these two characters, and I’ve
>   never seen anything that indicated any kind of cross-pollination.
>   Perhaps it’s just an idea that was floating out there in the ether
>   that more than one creator was lucky enough to tap into at about the
>   same time.

It doesn't seem I can get any better answer than this.